# How to capture syntax errors from formula entries in cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet which logs formula attempts by my students on another sheet in the same workbook. I want to see their different formula attempts when they submit the logs to me, but I'd especially like to see their syntax errors, although I'm not sure of the object or attribute to get the formula from before it is checked for syntax. The normal `range("A1").formula` is not changed when the syntax error occurs.

Example: 
In cell A1, `=TODAY(B1)` generates a syntax error and results in a message box with a warning. The user is then returned to the worksheet with the cell still in edit mode. I suspect no attribute of `range("A1")` has changed.

Do I need to get the attribute of a different object to find the formula the user attempted before the warning message?

I googled for days, and no luck. Any insight much appreciated.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can't run a macro while the user is editing a cell, and in order for the user to finish editing the cell (and therefore allow any macro you have to run) they must have already gotten rid of any syntax errors they had.

Comment: I suspect the same thing, but I was hoping there might be a convoluted workaraound. Maybe the only way is to install a keylogger (with full permission and transparency... on our machines) and capture all formulas, parse them for syntax errors using my own code (ouch) and analyse that way. I hope the resulting journal artical is good!